# Is __name__ a class level variable?

Tags: python, oop

Normally the class level attributes can be accessed through instance of this class
However for attributes like `__name__` , `__bases__` I cannot access them through an instance.
How / where are defined these attributes ?
See the code below:

```
class MyParentClass:
    k = 12

class MyClass(MyParentClass):
    pass

obj = MyClass()

print(MyClass.k)    # ok
print(MyClass.__name__)  # ok
print(obj.k) # ok
print(obj.__name__) # error
```

Answer (score 1):

They can not be accessed from the instance because they are not class attributes, but attributes of the class object.

Comment: So If I understand correctly `MyClass` object contains a class template (which is inherited by the sub-classes and is available on the objects instantiated from this class) plus some additional attributes (not part of the class template), which are coming from the `type` class and are available only on the class itself?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to get the name of the class:

```py
print(obj.__class__.__name__)
```

Output:

```
MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the more likely error is the spelling mistake:

```py
print(obj.__name) <----
```

it should have the dunder afterwards

Edit, i see that deceze has commented the same thing

Comment: Perhaps you could include working code alongside the failing code.

Comment: It is something related with formatting while posting. I corrected the initial post. It is `__name__`, not `__name`